# Unable to find a specification for `pop (~> 1.0)` in Podfile

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I want to install pop for my IOS project. I got this error when doing pod install:

Unable to find a specification for `pop (~> 1.0)`

Below is my Podfile:

target "xxx" do
pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
end

Any Idea?

Comment: `- Versions: 1.0.6, 1.0.5, 1.0.4, 1.0.3, 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0 [master repo]` there is no version `1.0` try `1.0.0`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I was able to work around it by replacing the line with:

```
pod 'pop', :git => 'https://github.com/facebook/pop.git', :commit => '203464a89dcf2e15b1ebdd53eb1f82e7d077460c'
```

That commit corresponds with the 1.0.7 release

Answer (score 0):

Try adding semicolon before target name

```
target :test do
  pod 'OCMock', '~> 2.0.1'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers! It turns out there were some problems with my mac. After I restart my laptop and updated the software, it worked!